# Using value/variable used in if.clause after the if

Tags: flutter, oop, if-statement, dart

I want to create a new address model. Doing so, beforehand I check a data structure if this contains specific information and then extract them and store it into a variable. After all if-clauses I want to use these variables to create a new object of type Address. However, all the in-between stored variables are not recognized:

```
final List type = c['types'];
          if (type.contains('street_number')) {
            final streetNumber = c['long_name'];
          }
          if (type.contains('route')) {
            final street = c['long_name'];
          }
          if (type.contains('locality')) {
            final city = c['long_name'];
          }
          if (type.contains('postal_code')) {
            final zipCode = c['long_name'];
          }
          final address = Address(
              country: null,
              postalCode: zipCode,   //Undefinex name 'zipCode'
              city: city,
              streetNumber: streetNumber,
              long: null,
              lat: null);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables which are declared in a code block will be removed after that block. So you have to declare that Variables before those blocks:

```
dynamic streetNumber;
if (type.contains('street_number')) {
   streetNumber = c['long_name'];
}
dynamic street;
if (type.contains('route')) {
    street = c['long_name'];
}
dynamic city;
if (type.contains('locality')) {
  city = c['long_name'];
}
dynamic zipCode;
if (type.contains('postal_code')) {
  zipCode = c['long_name'];
}
```